# Vue 2 and Vue 3 vnode similarity algorithm

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

There are two simple components:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="count++"> {{ count }} </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SmallButton',
  data: () => ({ count: 0 }),
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="isShow = !isShow"> Change button </button>

    <div v-if="isShow">
      <SmallButton />
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <SmallButton />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SmallButton from './SmallButton.vue';

export default {
  name: 'ParentComponent',
  components: { SmallButton },
  data: () => ({ isShow: true }),
};
</script>
```

In Vue 2 there is a problem when clicking "Change button": DOM is not updated.
This problem can be solved with `:key` attribute, but in the Vue 3 there is no such problem at all!

A read this article:
https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/rendering-mechanism.html 
but I didn't find an answer to the question there. Perhaps I misunderstood something.

I understand that the problem is in different approaches to comparing the old and new VDOM trees in Vue 2 and in Vue 3.

Where can I read about this improvement in Vue 3, which affects the behavior in the code examples above?

Comment: your v-if is switching out SmallButton for SmallButton? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Vue 2 does not switch it!

Comment: yeah because its cached, are you trying to clear the counter?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be counted as an improvement. More like the opposite, it's is not cached when it's expected. Any way, it's mandatory to use :key here because this is the way the framework will distinguish sibling elements with v-for, v-if etc

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, im trying to understand the difference of how vue 2 and vue 3 works. In new Vue 3 all works fine.

Comment: @EstusFlask, where can I read that the use of an attribute `key` is mandatory in **this situation**? But the fact is that everything works fine in Vue 3.

Comment: Here https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html#key , "Without keys, Vue uses an algorithm that minimizes element movement and tries to patch/reuse elements of the same type in-place as much as possible". This is what happens here, at least in Vue 2. It "sees" `<div><SmallButton /></div>` vnodes for v-if condition, and then the same for v-else. The same  concerns are applicable to both v-if and v-for for the siblings of the same type. Good to know that https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/key-attribute.html is the documented behaviour and not just a quirk of Vue renderer

Comment: @EstusFlask, thanks, I've already found the answer. This is, indeed, a change in Vue 3.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:
https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/key-attribute.html

> keys are no longer necessary on v-if/v-else/v-else-if branches, since **Vue now automatically generates** unique keys.